# Feign Client method level Logging

Tags: java, logging, feign

Is there mechanism in the Feign client to log at method level.

One can set the logging level globally or per class via propterties or java config:

```
logging: 
    level: 
      project: 
          user: 
            MyFeignClient: full
```

but am looking at method level logging specifically.

Thanks